# Local Parachain blocks not getting finalized - logs show websocket error

Tags: substrate-node-template, polkadot, substrate-parachain-template

I am following the [build a parachain](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/connect-a-local-parachain/)
however, after I run the parachain collator and the relay chain validators, and then make a `transfer` from one account to another (`Alice to Bob`) on the parachain using the `polkadotjs ui`. The transaction succeeds (from the event notification) but it seems like the parachain block is not finalized on the relay chain so the accounts values remain unchanged. I can see the following message on the parachain logs below

Note: I have followed the [tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/connect-a-local-parachain/) to setup the relay chain correctly

```
   2023-06-14 23:48:25.545 ERROR tokio-runtime-worker jsonrpsee_server::transport::ws: WS transport error: i/o error: Socket is not connected (os error 57); terminate connection: 2
```

Comment: What is your setup like? Are you running the Relay chain and parachain on the same  computer?

Comment: Yes, I am. For some reason, it is finalized now, and I made no changes. What I do notice is that initiallially, Alice account, which is the from account, had a balance of 1.0000 UNIT. After purging that chain state , after a day I saw that the balance is now 1000,000 UNIT, why was the balance 1.000 unit before, i do not see it on polkadot chain_spec where account balances are specified, if it is specified somewhere, why was it not showing 1000000UNIT the first time I tried

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is some problem in connecting your parachain to relay chain.

```
./target/release/parachain-template-node --name a1 --collator --force-authoring --chain raw-parachain-chainspec.json --base-path /tmp/parachain/a1 --port 40333 --ws-port 8844 -- --execution wasm --chain ../polkadot/customSpecRaw.json --port 30343 --ws-port 9977 --bootnodes /ip4/172.15.14.155/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWBh14B1a9Xh5WPPedT6EohwXNkKYvWJ3p2xt1GKndka1j
```

You can try this `command` for connecting your `parachain` to `relay chain`.Put the `ip address` of your system where relay chain is running and also the `local id` of the relay chain in this command.

Comment: Its local,For some reason, it is finalized now, and I made no changes. What I do notice is that initiallially, Alice account, which is the from account, had a balance of 1.0000 UNIT. After purging that chain state , after a day I saw that the balance is now 100,000 UNIT, why was the balance 1.000 unit before, i do not see it on polkadot chain_spec where account balances are specified, if it is specified somewhere, why was it not showing 1000000UNIT the first time I tried